# Qt Windows x64 build succeeds in IDE but not on the command line

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I have a Qt project I'm trying to automate. On Windows I build for both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms. I am using Visual Studio 2013. I have the following Qt Kits installed: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 MSVC2013 32bit, and Desktop Qt 5.5.1 MSVC2013 64bit. All four versions (32-bit debug and release, and 64-bit debug and release) can be built and run without any trouble from the IDE. Unfortunately, building from the command line fails with this error:

```
fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

My command-line system, intended for eventual use in a batch file, and run in my project directory, is:

```
pushd Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin
call vcvars32.bat
popd
md build64
cd build64
G:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-msvc2013 -o Makefile ..\Maps.pro
G:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
```

I use this command in a command window (after setting up the path using vcvars32 so that the Visual Studio tools like nmake, rc and link can be found) and get the error. Note that the command-line method works perfectly for my 32-bit build.

The **qmake** command line I use is copied from the one recorded in a comment in the Makefile created by the IDE, which claims it is the command used to create that makefile. I know that the "-spec win32-msvc2013" option looks strange, but it works when the IDE uses it.

The **jom** command line I use is the one used by the IDE, as logged by the Compile Output window.

The only thing I can think of is that Qt sets up some 'magic' environmental variables which I don't know about.

[Yes, I have googled very extensively and looked at other questions and answers here, and can't find anything that fits this case.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
pushd Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin
vcvars32.bat
popd
```

sets up environment for building for 32-bit architecture. Run `vcvars32.bat` from different directory (I think it should have `amd64` in its name, don't have Windows computer at the moment so can't say the exact directory name, but you'll figure out).

Or do

```
pushd "<DRIVE>:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio <Version>\Common7\Tools"
vsvars32 x64
popd
```

Update for VS2017:

For 64-bit architecture use this command:

```
"<DRIVE>:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<Version>\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
```

and for 32 bits:

```
"<DRIVE>:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<Version>\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a correct and very fast answer! I used the command "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\vc\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat" instead of the one I was using before, and the build now works.